# can't delete user after removing app

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm

I have a django project that has many different apps. We deleted one of the apps, and now when we try and delete a user it fails, complaining about a table from that app not existing. There are no references to that app, or table anywhere. Testing, I found that if I create the table the error goes away.

After googling and searching around I thought I had figured it out. The app was referenced in django_content_type and the content_type_id was referenced in auth_permission. So I deleted the rows with that content_type_id from both auth_permission and auth_permission, but I still get the error.

What do I need to do to remove references to this app so I can delete users?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1205.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_query_set(request))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
  960.             response = func(self, request, queryset)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py" in delete_selected
  35.         queryset, opts, request.user, modeladmin.admin_site, using)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in get_deleted_objects
  109.     collector.collect(objs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in collect
  160.             return super(NestedObjects, self).collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in collect
  225.                 elif sub_objs:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __nonzero__
  141.         return type(self).__bool__(self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __bool__
  135.             next(iter(self))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _result_iter
  123.                 self._fill_cache()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fill_cache
  927.                     self._result_cache.append(next(self._iter))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  301.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  775.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  130.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  120.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  173.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/auth/user/
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'motor.reflection_resource_listeners' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: do you have some unusual cache setting?

Comment: enable django query logging and see what equery is being executed (django.db.backends in loggers). YOu might already be able to see the query in your mysql logs

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know about django query logging. I usually just use brute force (and pdb) to find the query. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fully delete an app from Django you need to follow these steps:

1. Remove any references to the app from all other apps and models, make migrations and apply them. (This will delete all foreign key relations to the models you want to remove)
2. Comment out all the models for the app you want to remove and then make migrations and apply them. (This will drop all the tables for the models you want to delete)
3. After all references in other apps have been removed and the app itself has no models, you can delete the files for the whole app.
4. Finally you need to get rid of all the ContentType entries that were created on your initial migration run. You can do this by running the script found here: [Remove Content Types](http://www.marinamele.com/how-to-correctly-remove-a-model-or-app-in-django)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first 3 steps I had already done. It was the 4th step that I needed to do.